# Select with priority on a column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a multiple sql query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id, autor, dle_post.date AS newsdate, dle_post.date AS DATE, short_story AS story, dle_post.xfields AS xfields, title, descr, keywords, category, alt_name, comm_num AS comm_in_news, allow_comm, rating, news_read, flag, editdate, editor, reason, view_edit, tags,  '' AS output_comms
FROM dle_post
WHERE dle_post.approve =1
AND MATCH (
title, short_story, full_story, dle_post.xfields
)
AGAINST (
'test'
)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

How can I priorities the `title` column, so results from `title` will be first?

Comment: @MikeB than the results not accurate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repeat the `match` in the `order by`:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id, autor, dle_post.date AS newsdate, dle_post.date AS DATE, short_story AS story, dle_post.xfields AS xfields, title, descr, keywords, category, alt_name, comm_num AS comm_in_news, allow_comm, rating, news_read, flag, editdate, editor, reason, view_edit, tags,  '' AS output_comms
FROM dle_post
WHERE dle_post.approve =1
AND MATCH (
title, short_story, full_story, dle_post.xfields
)
AGAINST (
'test'
)
order by MATCH (title) AGAINST ('test') desc
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

By the way, you shouldn't use `limit` without an `order by` clause.  What you probably want is something more like this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id, autor, dle_post.date AS newsdate, dle_post.date AS DATE,
       short_story AS story, dle_post.xfields AS xfields, title, descr, keywords,
       category, alt_name, comm_num AS comm_in_news, allow_comm, rating, news_read, flag,
       editdate, editor, reason, view_edit, tags,  '' AS output_comms,
       match(title, short_story, full_story, dle_post.xfields
            ) against ('test') as Relevancy
FROM dle_post
WHERE dle_post.approve =1
having Relevancy > 0
order by MATCH (title) AGAINST ('test') desc, Relevancy desc
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this [example](http://dev.mysql.com/doc//refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html):

```
SELECT *, ( (1.3 * (MATCH(title) AGAINST ('+term +term2' IN BOOLEAN MODE))) + (0.6 *(MATCH(text) AGAINST ('+term +term2' IN BOOLEAN MODE))) ) AS relevance
FROM [table_name]
WHERE ( MATCH(title,text) AGAINST ('+term +term2' IN BOOLEAN MODE) )
HAVING relevance > 0
ORDER BY relevance DESC;
```

You basically add weights to your columns and sort by the sum of these weights. MySQL has several good search engines that can perform this function and I recommend [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/).